# Layer Masking in Photoshop CS6

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, cs6, mask

What would be the best way to subtract the radial (shape 1) lines from the grey ellipse (ellipse 1) so that the background image (ios7 wallpaper) would be visible as a "notch" effect and so the background image remains visible in the centers as well?

Tutorial from http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/tutorials/flat-design-countdown-timer/

Thanks!

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Command/Ctrl-click the layer thumbnail for Shape 1.
- Command/Ctrl-Shift-click the layer thumbnail for the Ellipse layer
- This loads them both as a selection.
- Choose Select > Inverse from the menu
- Highlight the iOS background layer
- Click the Layer Mask icon at the bottom of the Layers Panel